# How to use references in JustinRainbow JsonValidator

Tags: php, jsonschema

Can someone tell me how to make the JustinRainbow Json schema validator be able to find references.

This is the schema of foobar I'm trying to validate:

```
{
  "title": "foobar schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pagination": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/pagination"
    }
  },
  "required": ["pagination"]
}
```

And the definition of the pagination schema is contained in a separate file on my computer.

Trying to validate that without telling the JSON validator how to resolve references like this:

```
$uriRetriever = new JsonSchema\Uri\UriRetriever();
$refResolver = new JsonSchema\RefResolver($uriRetriever, $uriResolver);
$schema = $refResolver->resolve("file://".realpath(__DIR__."/foobar.json"));
```

Gives an error message:

```
File: file://features/foobar.json is found, but could not resolve fragment: #/definitions/pagination (JsonSchema\Exception\UnresolvableJsonPointerException)
```

Which is fair enough as there is no way for the validator to know how to find the file that contains the pagination schema definition....so how can I tell the RefResolver how to find the definition of the pagination schema?

I would prefer to be able to resolve the file through the local filesystem, rather than having to use URL's on a webserver.

Comment: can this help you http://json-schema.org/example2.html

Comment: Not really - I need a code example that shows how to tell the library that something like "#/definitions/diskDevice" can be found in a particular file.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of reference used in your schema is a [json pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) referring to another part of your schema file. You need to specify definition/pagination properties to get rid of the error.

```
{
  "title": "foobar schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pagination": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/pagination"
    }
  },
  "required": ["pagination"],
  "definitions": {
        "pagination": {
       
        }
    }
}
```

In order to refer to a definition in an other file you can write something like:

```
"pagination": {
  "$ref": "pagination.schema.json#"
}
```

Or even specify a particular node in the external file:

```
"pagination": {
  "$ref": "external_definitions.schema.json#/definitions/pagination"
}
```

The `external_definitions.schema.json` / `pagination.schema.json` should be looked for in the same folder as your schema containing the reference. The library should also provide some api to configure this lookup.

In my project I use JustinRainbow JsonValidator for php. It does not allow to provide a custom resolver, but the location where the referred files are search for can be influenced by "id" value in the schema.

Example, schema in `main.schema.json`:

```
{
  "id": "http://myweb.com/schemas/main.schema.json#",
  "title": "foobar schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pagination": {
       "$ref": "pagination.schema.json#"
    }
  },
  "required": ["pagination"]
}
```

when validating this schema, so the validator tries to load the pagination.schema.json using:

```
php_get_contents('http://myweb.com/schemas/pagination.schema.json');
```